# Asana API - list of open and closed tasks for a workspace(including unassigned to me)

Tags: asana

Is it possible to retrieve a list of open and closed tasks(totals) for a workspace(or organization) including both assigned(to me or others) and unassigned tasks?

If this is not possible,

is it then a possibility to do a combined query for a few projects(like project={project_id1},{project_id2})? Also in this case I would like it to return both assigned and unassigned tasks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can only get tasks for a single project or a single assignee (and we don't have a way to query for unassigned tasks in a workspace via the API). When you request tasks for a project, you get all assigned and unassigned tasks by default.